# Insert Statement Using Same Variable Multiple Times

Tags: c#, sql-server

A few float teachers need to be assigned to multiple classes in the database.  This statement errors out with `Error of the variable name @Teacher has already been declared.  Variable names must be unique wihtin a query batch or stored procedure`

This is my syntax.  What should I change to make this happen:

```
private void btnOne_Click()
{
string insertstatement = "INSERT INTO tbl_TeacherInfo (Teacher,Grade) VALUES (@Teacher, @Grade)";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    using (SqlCommand comm1 = new SqlCommand(insertstatement, conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        comm1.CommandText = insertstatement;
        comm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Teacher", "Mrs Hart");
        comm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Grade", "1st");
        comm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Teacher", "Mrs Hart");
        comm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Grade", "2nd");
        comm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Teacher", "Mrs Hart");
        comm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Grade", "3rd");
        comm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Teacher", "Mrs Hart");
        comm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Grade", "4th");
        comm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Teacher", "Mrs Hart");
        comm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Grade", "5th");
        comm1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You can use Table Variable Parameter instead of multiple inserts.

Comment: You are only executing your command once and passing parameters to it 5 times, rather than executing 5 times with different values

Comment: Also, FWIW, you don't need to assign `CommandText` if you've already passed it to the ctor.

Comment: @RyanDansie I added the comm1.ExecuteNonQuery(); statement at the end of each individual insert, but still get the error?

Comment: @BradChristie - Good Tip - I didn't realize that was an option.

Comment: @RyanDansie - example?

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var teacher = "Mrs Hart";
var grades = new[]{ "1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th" };
var sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_TeacherInfo (Teacher,Grade) "
        + "VALUES (@Teacher, @Grade)";

using (var conn = new SqlConnection(/* connectionString */))
{
  conn.Open(); // Open once and share it

  // share the command
  using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
  {
    // assign the shared value across all queries, and
    // add a placeholder for the revolving parameter
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Teacher", teacher);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Grade", String.Empty); // placeholder

    // iterate over the grades (1st, 2nd, etc.)
    foreach (var grade in grades)
    {
      cmd.Parameters["@Grade"].Value = grade; // change @Grade
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Execute with these two values
    }
  }

  conn.Close(); // cleanup
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your mistake is assigning parameters with the same name (`@Teacher` and `@Grade`) more than once. I would suggest creating a separate method that accepts two parameters (`teacher` and `grade`) and inserts one record to `tbl_TeacherInfo` as below

```
private void InsertRecord(string teacher, string grade)
{
    string insertstatement = "INSERT INTO tbl_TeacherInfo (Teacher,Grade) VALUES (@Teacher, @Grade)";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand comm1 = new SqlCommand(insertstatement, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            comm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Teacher", teacher);
            comm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Grade", grade);
            comm1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

then call the above method in `btnOne_Click` method

```
private void btnOne_Click()
{
    InsertRecord("Mrs Hart", "1st");
    InsertRecord("Mrs Hart", "2nd");
    InsertRecord("Mrs Hart", "3rd");
    InsertRecord("Mrs Hart", "4th");
    InsertRecord("Mrs Hart", "5th");
}
```

Comment: I do like that you refactored it into a shared method, just maybe should also accept a `SqlConnection`. Not that a close/reopen is _that_ expensive, but I feel like it could/should be reused whenever possible.